# Remove/Hide last occurrence of a string after a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a wp_nav_menu structure that outputs a menu with only the a link and also an after string with the link. How can I remove or hide the last occurrence (The one after the last link) of that after string with jQuery? See code below.

```
<p id="para"> 
<a href="#">Item One</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
<a href="#">Item Two</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
<a href="#">Item Three</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
</p>
```

I'm trying to remove the last occurrence of "`&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;`". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of nodeValue

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7sy9W/

```
$('#para a:last-child')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "";
```

EDIT:: Pure javascript in case you not use jquery. Actually this might be better

```
document.getElementById("para").lastChild.nodeValue = '';
```

Comment: The first option works for me. You understood exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

since you haven't shown any code.. i'm gonna give you a silly one.. it works though...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $a = $("#para a") ;
$("#para").empty() ;
$a.each(function() {
  $("#para").append(this);
});
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bA47P/)

Comment: Sorry for not providing more detail for you. The option you are suggesting, removes all occurrence of the string. I just wanted to remove the last one after the last link. Solution was found. Thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 1):

idk wat exct u want bt i had tried something with php

```
<?php
$str= '<p id="para"> 
<a href="#">Item One</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
<a href="#">Item Two</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; 
<a href="#">Item Three</a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
</p>';

echo substr($str, 0, strrpos( $str, ' ') );
?>
```

Comment: I really wanted to do a jQuery. Got the solution. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

**HTML**

```
<p id="para"> 
    <a href="#">Item One</a><span> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; </span>
    <a href="#">Item Two</a> <span>&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; </span>
    <a href="#">Item Three</a><span> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#para a+span').last().hide()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPxMj/

**EDIT**

If it is not possible to place the extra data within a span element (as informed in the comments) then you may try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#para').contents().each(function(i){
        if(i==$('#para').contents().length-1){
          $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPxMj/1/

Comment: The string is not enclosed in a `<span>`. it is automatically generated.

Comment: My bad i didn't realize it, that is why i suggested a better design. Now, i updated the answer to cover this case.